# grep with PTR records and domain+TLD match

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I'm trying to determine if the domain+TLD are present in a list, after running the `host` command for an IP.

My script looks like this:

```
while read ip; do
  PTR=$(host $ip | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev | sed 's/\.$//')
  if grep -q "$PTR" list.txt
  then
    echo "Match in list"
  else
    echo "No match in list"
  fi
done <ips.txt
```

The `list.txt` will contain:

```
dns.google
shodan.io
```

If I run my script for 8.8.8.8, which returns **dns.google** the script works as expected. If I run it for 198.20.99.130 it will fail (not match) as the result is **census4.shodan.io**.

Is there a way I can have `grep` match *only* if the domain+TLD (in this case shodan.io) is in the list?

While **census4.shodan.io** should match the list.txt, a domain like **shodan.io.example.net** shouldn't.

Comment: This question could be better written.  You've managed to ask for (DNS) wildcard matches for all domain names that end with any of the the label suffixes specified in the list file without using the words "wildcard", "any", "suffix", "ends", or even (outwith the title) "with".

Comment: I'd just get the last two dot bits with awk. That should match with grep: `PTR=$(host $ip | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | awk 'BEGIN {FS="."}{ print $2"."$3}' | rev)`

Comment: @MichaelD. that actually got me pretty close. Only problem is that for IPs that do not hold a PTR record, the output of the command to check the PTR record is ".", and that is being considered a match.

Comment: Your matching is broken because you're trying to match `SUBDOMAIN.domain.tld` on the list containing `domain.tld`. Try changing the grep to following `grep -q "$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {print $(NF-1),$NF}' <<<$PTR)" list.txt`

Comment: @t988GF you let the bounty you offered expire without accepting an answer and so you lost the 200 points anyway but they weren't awarded to anyone trying to help you. Does [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607605/133219) not solve your problem? If not, please do ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing command is failing because it's doing partial regexp instead of full string matching. It'll also be very slow and non-portable.

Do this instead:

```
< ips.txt xargs -n 1 host |
awk '
    NR==FNR { list[$0]; next }
    {
        n = split($NF,f,/[.]/)
        domtld = f[n-2] "." f[n-1]
        print (domtld in list ? "Match" : "No match"), "in list"
    }
' list.txt -
Match in list
Match in list
```

The above will run faster and be more robust and portable than a shell loop with a bunch of pipes to various other commands. It just uses `xargs` to call `host` 1 line at a time on the contents of `list.txt` (so no need for you to write a loop) and pipe the output of that to a single `awk` script. The `awk` script reads `list.txt` once at startup (as opposed to once per domain as in a loop+grep solution), stores the values in an array named `list[]`, then takes the `host` output one line at a time, isolates the domain+tld, and uses a hash lookup to see if it's in the `list` array to print the desired output. No need to worry about partial matches or regexp metachars like with your existing `grep` command - everything's just using full, literal strings.